# JaCoCo code coverage engine in Jenkins with Sonar

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I need to configure JaCoCo code coverage engine in Jenkins with Sonar.

I have made the following entries in the sonar-project.properties file

```
sonar.projectKey=projectX:projectX
sonar.projectName=projectX
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sources=src
tests=test
binaries=workspace/stage/main/classes,workspace/stage/test/classes
libraries=workspace/stage/artifact/lib/*.jar
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/jacoco.exec
```

I have also written the following ant tasks:

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
</taskdef>
<target name="jacoco-coverage">
<jacoco:coverage enabled="true" destfile="jacoco.exec">
<junit fork="true" forkmode="once" includeAntRuntime="true" maxmemory="512M"                                                                                                                                 printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="false">
<test name="com.test.HelloWorld"/>
<batchtest todir="workspace/stage/test/classes/">
<fileset dir="../test" includes="**/*.java"/>
</batchtest>
<classpath>
<path refid="classpath.test"/>
<pathelement location="workspace/stage/test/classes/" />
</classpath>
</junit>
</jacoco:coverage>
</target>

<target name="jacoco-report">
<jacoco:report>
<executiondata>
<file file="jacoco.exec" />
</executiondata>
<structure name="Example Project">
<classfiles>
<fileset dir="workspace/stage/test/classes" />
</classfiles>
<sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
<fileset dir="test" />
</sourcefiles>
</structure>
<html destdir="report" />
</jacoco:report>
</target>
```

The jacoco.exec file is not getting generated from "jacoco-coverage" so the "jacoco-report" target is failing.

Any input, pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check our sample project here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/ant/ut-ant-jacoco-reuseReports

This should help you.

Comment: My test case is running fine but it is not creating output file "jacoco.exec". Hence can't proceed for report generation.

Comment: I had to re-form the classpath from the example to make it work right.

Answer (score 0):

The following settings without any properties work for me:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <!--write repo  rts into surefire-reports dir so jacoco can pick them up-->
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire reports</reportsDirectory>
                <!--add jacoco-->
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName> <!-- default: argLine -->
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</destFile> <!-- agent -->
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</dataFile> <!-- report -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```